# How to group, pivot and count in R

Tags: r

Using the `GermanCredit` dataset from the `caret` library.

```
library("caret")
data(GermanCredit)
```

After filtering this down a bit

```
credit.all <- GermanCredit[,c(10, 1:9, 11:13, 16:19)]
attach(credit.all)
names(credit.all)
```

We have these names

```
 [1] "Class"                          "Duration"                      
 [3] "Amount"                         "InstallmentRatePercentage"     
 [5] "ResidenceDuration"              "Age"                           
 [7] "NumberExistingCredits"          "NumberPeopleMaintenance"       
 [9] "Telephone"                      "ForeignWorker"                 
[11] "CheckingAccountStatus.lt.0"     "CheckingAccountStatus.0.to.200"
[13] "CheckingAccountStatus.gt.200"   "CreditHistory.ThisBank.AllPaid"
[15] "CreditHistory.PaidDuly"         "CreditHistory.Delay"           
[17] "CreditHistory.Critical"
```

What I need to do is pivot at summarize on two of these columns, something I know how to do in SQL like this.

```
SELECT
  Class
, SUM(CASE WHEN `CreditHistory.Critical` = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Critical
, SUM(CASE WHEN `CreditHistory.Critical` = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NotCritical
, SUM(CASE WHEN `CreditHistory.Critical` = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(*) AS PctCritical
FROM `credit.all`
GROUP BY
  Class
```

Which would produce something like this
[image]

However, I am struggling mightily to get a foothold in R, using books and Google, it seems I should use `reshape2` `melt` and `dcast` to achieve something like this.  What I have tried are basically variants of this:

```
library(reshape2)
credit.melted <- melt(credit.all[,c(1,17)], ID=c("name", "Class"))
dcast(credit.melted, Class~CreditHistory.Critical, nrow, fill=0)
```

But all of my attempts with these functions have produced errors too cryptic and too common to understand what I am doing wrong.

```
Error in vapply(indices, fun, .default) : values must be length 1,
 but FUN(X[[1]]) result is length 0
```

Sometimes my random permutations of the function calls produce slightly different error output, but nothing that points me in the right direction.

Question: How can I do the pivoted summary similar to the SQL result using R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't really consider this a pivot. You're not trying to use a pivot command in SQL. You can use `dplyr` to follow the exact same method as your SQL:

```
library(dplyr)
credit.all %>%
    group_by(Class) %>%
    summarize(Critical = sum(CreditHistory.Critical == 1),
              NotCritical = sum(CreditHistory.Critical == 0),
              PctCritical = mean(CreditHistory.Critical == 1))
# # A tibble: 2 x 4
#   Class Critical NotCritical PctCritical
#   <fct>    <int>       <int>       <dbl>
# 1 Bad         50         250       0.167
# 2 Good       243         457       0.347
```

Since it's a binary column the `== 1` isn't really necessary, but I leave it in because (a) it's more similar to your SQL code, and (b) if there were other values but you wanted the count of 1s, this would be the way to do it. However, you could get the same results a little more simply like this:

```
credit.all %>%
    group_by(Class) %>%
    summarize(Critical = sum(CreditHistory.Critical),
              NotCritical = n() - Critical,
              PctCritical = Critical / n())
```

---

If you really want a pivot approach, we can go that route, it just seems less straightforward. Your data is already in a long format, so we don't need to `melt`, we can just cast:

```
pivot = dcast(Class ~ CreditHistory.Critical, data = credit.all)
pivot
# Using CreditHistory.Critical as value column: use value.var to override.
# Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length
#   Class   0   1
# 1   Bad 250  50
# 2  Good 457 243
```

You could then rename the columns and calculate the percentages:

```
names(pivot)[2:3] = c("NotCritical", "Critical")
pivot$PctCritical = with(pivot, Critical / (Critical + NotCritical)
```